# page resolve url not finding the path

Tags: c#

I have following code

```
  <link href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/ReportBuilderOutput/Style/jquery-ui.css") %>?Ver=<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsCssVersion"].ToString() %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but its rendering like this

http://mysite.com/Reports/%3C%=%20Page.ResolveUrl%28%22~/ReportBuilderOutput/Style/jquery-ui.css%22%29%20%%3E?Ver=%3C%=%20ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[%22JsCssVersion%22].ToString%28%29%20%%3E

I have given page resolve url for two others js, and those are working fine

what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there runat = "server" in head